# Beginning Alloy - "Three Logics in One"

Tags: alloy

One of the first exercises in [Software Abstractions](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/software-abstractions) is to convert example properties from the relational calculus style to the predicate calculus style.

Despite studying the Logic chapter in the book i still can't confidently say which is and which isn't an example of the predicate, navigation expression and relational styles.

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You've asked for advice, and not for a definition of the three styles of expression.  My advice is:  don't worry about it.

I've been using Alloy for years now, and I can't remember ever running into any problem whose solution depended on the distinction.  You can think of the discussion in *Software Abstractions* as a way of making clear some of the ways in which Alloy offers more than one way to express the same idea, and using names to make clear that in crucial ways it's an intentional property of the language design, not an accident.

If you're writing Alloy for a group project, it may matter which style you pick at any moment; if you're writing for yourself, you could do worse than write things down in whatever way makes clearest to you what the expression is doing (and makes it easiest to tell that you've got the expression formulated correctly).

Comment: Thanks, i'm just a bit disheartened as it is the first exercise. I should persevere.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be disheartened. As Michael Sperberg-McQueen explains, it's not essential and you should just not worry and move on. I put this in the book to explain to people coming from different logical backgrounds how Alloy could be used in a style they were familiar with: the predicate style for people familiar with traditional first order logic; the navigational style for those familiar with writing runtime assertions in languages like Java, and with OCL; and the relational style for those who had seen Z. For those unfamiliar with these, that section turned out to be quite unenlightening!